# Erlang ping node problem

Tags: erlang, ping

I made in erlang shell:

```
1> node().
nonode@nohost
```

But

```
2> net_adm:ping(node()). 
pang
```

Why? What's problem? Why not pong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't start Erlang with `-name` or `-sname`, which means that the distribution subsystem was not started.  Try this:

```
$ erl -sname mynode
Erlang R14B02 (erts-5.8.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.3  (abort with ^G)
(mynode@foobar)1> node().
mynode@foobar
(mynode@foobar)2> net_adm:ping(node()).
pong
```

Comment: in my case, there is no `net_adm` package

Comment: @weima Have you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219351)?

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure, but You started erl without "-name" oder "-sname". I believe net_adm:ping/1 only works in a distributed mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to ping an erlang node but getting a `pang`.

Check the cookie with `erlang:get_cookie()` it will be some random string set the cookie of another node with `erlang:set_cookie(Node, Cookie)` or you could pass the cookie to the flag `-setcookie`

for example:

```
(foo@earth) erlang:get_cookie().
ASYRQKVNIFHWIIJQZIYN

(foo@earth) erlang:set_cookie(node(), 'secret cookie'). 
true 

net:ping('mongooseim@localhost').
pong
```

Check out the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html)