# What could cause the `net_adm` kernel Erlang module to be unavailable?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-shell

Installed Erlang (releases from 19 to 22) using

- the Nix package manager
- `apt`
- and compiling from source

on **Ubuntu 18.04 with Xmonad** and **Debian 9 running in the cloud**, but every time, `net_adm` is not available through the Erlang shell event though other kernel modules are.

I assume that this is caused by an external system configuration because couldn't find anything about this online, so people are not complaining about it. ([Only found one person so far.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539525/erlang-ping-node-problem#comments-5539859))

Comment: Which version of erlang is this ? 22.1 ? Which packages did you install?

Comment: Good point, updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of ashamed to admit that I am an idiot, but `net_adm` was there all this time...

For some reason, it wouldn't autocomplete on the `erl` shell, but once typed out starting with `net_adm:` (such as the non-existent `net_adm:ping()`), and executed it, it would start recognizing the module, and provide a list of available functions when hitting the Tab key.